# include external url in html

Tags: html, jsp

Can i include external URL in my HTML and get the content in HTML , just like jstl  , so that we dont we dont have to have connectivity issue or use java code .
If we use jstl it has to open socket and do processing instead dirtecly include external url
currently i am implementing this way

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page
    language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>google</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body>
<c:import uri="http://google.com" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `so that we dont we dont have to have connectivity issue` how would you prevent that? Are you prepared to use caching?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this using vanilla HTML.  The closest you can get is an `iframe`, but that seems like it's not what you're looking for.  Your best bet is to use some server-side language as you are, and then consider caching the results if you're concerned about load/connectivity issues.

Your caching strategy can be either inside your app or at the HTTP level (e.g. using something like [Varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/).

Comment: I know, but I don't think it's possible.  Maybe you can use an iframe to achieve your goals?